Forgot lock screen PIN
Imagine I forgot the PIN for my lock screen.  Is there an alternative way to unlock my locked Android phone or tablet?  Other than resetting my device, and losing any data that was not backed up?
I could make sure not to reboot my device, because after rebooting the device, the PIN would be the only option.  But let's say I do not use fingerprint or face recognition, so I could not use those to back up any further data before I reset my device.
Let's say I did not write my PIN on a piece of paper, or a password manager like Google Passwords.

I did start looking at the tag wiki, like it recommends. But the top links seem a bit old. https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/locked-out/info

I am sorry for anyone in this situation.  The answer is almost certainly no. You are out of luck.
Contents

Can I unlock an Android device using my Google Account password?
Can I unlock an Android device using my Google Account password, and the "Find My Device" app or website?
Can I unlock an Android device using "Smart Lock"?
Can I unlock a Samsung Galaxy device using my Samsung Account password?
Can Samsung unlock a Samsung Galaxy device, if I show proof of purchase?
Can I pay someone to unlock an Android device?

1. Can I unlock an Android device using my Google Account password?
This is no longer possible.  The feature was removed in 2014, when Android 5.0 was released.
It is only possible on ancient devices using Android 4.4 and below.

Android help: Can't unlock your Android device
howtogeek.com: What to do if you forget your Android phone's PIN, pattern or password

2. Can I unlock an Android device using my Google Account password in the "Find My Device" app or website?
This feature has been removed.  There is no way to do this, even on old devices.
In a previous version of Find My Device (originally called Android Device Manager), the Lock button allowed you to  replace your current lock screen with a temporary password.
Note that in the current version of Find My Device, the Lock button has been replaced with Secure device:


Spiceworks forum: 2018: How to unlock my device using android device manager

3. Can I unlock an Android device using "Smart Lock" instead?
Smart Lock will not unlock a locked device.  To clarify this, it was eventually renamed to Extend Unlock.
You will not be able enable Extend Unlock if you have not already enabled it enabled.  Enabling Extend Unlock requires entering the PIN, but you have forgotten the PIN.  You cannot enable Extend Unlock using your fingerprint or face.
Extend Unlock can only keep your device unlocked for four hours or less.
If you do not want to lose data / photos / whatever is stored on your device, then you need to make sure that data is backed up immediately.

Android support: Choose when your Android phone can stay unlocked
2019 Android support: Choose when your Android device can stay unlocked

4. Can I unlock a Samsung Galaxy device using my Samsung account password?
The Samsung Remote Unlock option was removed in 2023.  This was an optional feature, that you had to specifically set up in advance.


SmartThings Community: No "Unlock" Option for Galaxy Device
Google search: Samsung "remote unlock" removed site:www.reddit.com

I understand this hurts people, and was handled badly.  It would be nice if Samsung could provide an opt-in PIN backup service, like how Windows laptops and tablets etc can be recovered using Microsoft Account recovery options.  Personally I wouldn't bother, based on my impressions of Samsung support.  However, it is certainly convenient for Google that the competing manufacturer is not able to differentiate here.
5. Can Samsung unlock a Samsung Galaxy device, if I show proof of purchase?
Your Android device is securely encrypted, using your PIN.  Samsung does not store a copy of people's PIN, in any circumstances (see above).
Samsung online support is sometimes unable to understand or apologize for this, but it is true.  If they suggest otherwise, please read the experiences linked below.
Staff at Samsung Service Centre could talk to you about this, and help you erase and reset your own device.  They might also suggest safe places to store a copy of your new PIN.

Samsung Canada: What can you do if you forgot the PIN, pattern or password of your Galaxy device
Samsung Community: comments in response to online moderator

6. Can I pay someone to unlock my Android device?
You are welcome to send me as much money as you like.  You could also ask for help by posting online on twitter.com, for example.  On such networks, many people offer to let you send them money!
Please be aware that neither of those methods will help you unlock your phone.
